# git: java git api for fetching git notes from a repository

Tags: java, git

Is there a java api for git, which allows for fetching git notes from a repository?
I looked at http://server001.agilebackoffice.org/nexus/content/repositories/atlassian/com/xiplink/jira/git/jira-git-plugin/0.6/ but it looks like it doesnt seem to support git notes. Any ideas where to look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) might have what you're looking for, specifically http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/notes/NoteMap.html.

For instance, looking up the note for a specific commit can be done with:

```
Repository repo = ...

RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
NoteMap map = NoteMap.newEmptyMap();
Ref ref = repo.getRef("refs/notes/commits");

if (ref != null) {
  RevCommit notesCommit = walk.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId());
  map = NoteMap.read(walk.getObjectReader(), notesCommit);
  map.getNote(notesCommit.getId());
}
```

Comment: not much of a java expert, but how to display all the notes to the standard output?

Comment: You could go through the NoteMap via an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Java). After getting each note with [Iterator.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29), you could print the string returned by [Note.toString()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/notes/Note.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: i tried that approach, but it gives me the filenames in the refs/notes/commits.. I am looking for the note messages of each commit.. Apart from reading the content of those files, is there a way to get the note messages, just wanna know???

Comment: any suggestions anyone?